# Disable window shadow on 10.11 / 10.12?

Tags: macos

Like in the title, I've used ShadowKiller (very old but worked until 10.11) but it doesn't work in 10.11 and 10.12 as well (tried disabling SIP).

I've tried using the command line trick, toggle-osx-shadows from github and couple of others, it seems that something changed in 10.11

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: The shadowhide method when taking screencapture is also not working in 10.12 Sierra.

Comment: Why would anyone want to do this? Just curious.

Comment: There are couple of use cases, like tiling window managers for example - normally shadows overlap on other app's window which doesn't look good. I do it for pure aesthetic reasons as well, it looks better that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**edit 01-11-2019: Works on Mojave.**

There is a solution - plugin called [winBuddy](https://github.com/w0lfschild/winBuddy) which is available through [MacForge](https://www.macenhance.com/macforge) (previously known as mySIMBL).

It allows you to turn off window shadow and/or window borders for every app.

I've just tested it and it seems to [work properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp1FM.jpg), there are some minor glitches here and there but nothing major.

Minor glitches include:

- You can't change window options for apps which don't have menu - like Bartender for example
- You can't change window options for some apps, as winBuddy does not show up under 'Window' in menu.

Comment: This is a great find. Thanks for sharing it! I see this issue pop up regularly in various forums etc and now I'll be able to offer a solution! :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Comment: This is fantastic! And also, the main fork of winBuddy now has "Hide Shadows" turned on by default... so this is a very nice solution.

The only thing to remember is you have to disable System Integrity Protection to complete the SIMBL install.

Comment: Mojave reporting, nothing works.

Comment: @jason - See my last edit, mySIMBL is now [MacForge](https://www.macenhance.com/macforge).