# How can I remove the window shadow in El Capitan?

Tags: macos

1. I tried ShadowKiller and ShadowSweeper, they do not work anymore on El Capitan.
2. I tried to disable System Integrity Protection, but it does not work.
3. toggle-osx-shadows also does not work: https://github.com/puffnfresh/toggle-osx-shadows/issues/17

Does anyone have other way? Thank you!

Comment: Same experience here - ShadowKiller no longer works in El Capitan, and toggle-osx-shadows didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[copied from my question about the same issue:](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/262958/145918)

**edit 01-11-2019: Works on Mojave.**

There is a solution - plugin called [winBuddy](https://github.com/w0lfschild/winBuddy) which is available through [MacForge](https://www.macenhance.com/macforge) (previously known as mySIMBL).

It allows you to turn off window shadow and/or window borders for every app.

I've just tested it and it seems to [work properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp1FM.jpg), there are some minor glitches here and there but nothing major.

Minor glitches include:

- You can't change window options for apps which don't have menu - like Bartender for example
- You can't change window options for some apps, as winBuddy does not show up under 'Window' in menu.

Answer (score 0):

To quote many sources, namely Reddit and Life Hacker(to disable system integrity protection):

1. Reboot your Mac into Recovery Mode by restarting your computer and holding down <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> until the Apple logo appears on your screen.
2. Click Utilities > Terminal.
3. In the Terminal window, type in `csrutil disable` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Restart your Mac.

This *should* work.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this can make your operating system less secure so it's worth reading about System Integrity Protection before you chose to disable it.

Comment: You can disable SIP, proceed to make changes and then reenable SIP. IMHO It's going to be okay, SIP didn't even exist before El Captian.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple System Integrity Protection prevents system files from being tampered with including styling of the UI. For this reason you cannot modify the window without disabling the System Integrity Protection. However doing so may put your Mac in danger. Therefore if the SIP was disabled malware or malicious content could modify or corrupt important system files which are required for the OS to run normally. However the side effect of this is restricted customization.

Comment: I'm assuming that's supposed to be "cannot modify" instead of "can". To improve your answer, consider explaining _why_ a Mac would be "in danger" with SIP disabled.

Comment: This is why we shouldn’t instead of why we can’t. In fact with extra of system security like ensuring the Apps you install are from trusted sources and always conscious of what you are doing. It is fairy safe to turn that off. NB GitHub apps are not considered as a trusted source...