# 1 pixel gap between window top and menu bar

Tags: macos

MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)

I have a 1 pixel gap between the top of the window and menu bar and I can't move the window close to the menu bar.

[image: Screenshot showing one pixel gap between top of window and menu bar]

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Yes - I solve this by coloring the top part of my desktop to match the shadow color.

That way, we don’t need to mind the gap.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be the design of the Safari window.  Safari (and other Apple apps) have a grey shadow border in dark theme and black in light theme :

[image: Safari]
[image: Safari 2]

It seems the color of the border is unaffected by the background - here is dark mode with colorful wallpaper and the border is still grey.

[image: Safari 3]

Whereas Firefox keeps a black border for both themes and so it doesn't show in dark mode.

[image: Firefox]
[image: Firefox 2]
[image: Firefox 3]

Looking at other apps there seems to be a mix.  Word acts like Safari while ITerm2 acts like Firefox.

There doesn't seem to be any way to remove this in Mojave - see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343760/how-can-i-remove-turn-off-shadows-in-macos-10-14?noredirect=1).  Older fixes/tweaks (like [Toggle OSX shadows](https://github.com/puffnfresh/toggle-osx-shadows)) [don't work](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210187/how-can-i-remove-the-window-shadow-in-el-capitan) any more.

Comment: But in question's screenshot, I can see red and white alternating strips which means there is a gap..  Could you change your BG to something in the defaults and then try?

Comment: @ankii - if I change background to colourful (for example the built in `chroma 2`) it doesn't change the colour of the window border - it remains gray as above - only the menubar changes.  I'll add a picture.

Comment: So the gap is due to the translucent border is what you mean? If yes, it wasn't clear to me immediately.

Comment: I think so - and thanks for the suggestion about coloured BG.  You can see it a bit on the last Firefox picture under `Help`- the colour is bleeding through slightly.  I assume if you could remove the shadow around the window (which you can't) it would disappear.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3803n.png I have pitch black border  then (or 0 pixel gap, or both).. 10.14.5. reduce transparency unchecked.