# How can I remove/turn off shadows in macOS 10.14

Tags: macos, mojave

I think this has been asked somewhere for [lots of](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209069/disable-window-shadow-on-10-11-10-12) [versions](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/7rox13/anyone_know_to_disable_window_shadow_on_high/) of OS X/macOS and it seems like it's always a different answer.

I'm trying to remove the shadows around windows and the shadow below the menu bar in macOS 10.14.  I'm not using Dark Mode.

[image]

I've tried various options from previous OS versions including [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) and Reducing transparency in Preferences.

I'm not interested in turning off SIP.

Are there any options out there?

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers in your links all involve using SIMBL -- which is a third-party app that performs a variety of system 'hacks' or extensions. That (and the absence of any known `defaults write` key, suggests that removing shadows is not something that Apple have provided.

Answer (score 0):

This terminal command should work:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow -bool true
```

Source: [macOS Mojave: How to Disable Mojave Screenshot Shadows | The Mac Observer](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/quick-tip/disable-mojave-screenshot-shadows/)

Comment: This might work for screenshots but I am trying to remove shadows from windows and the menu bar.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I'm not sure how to disable shadows in macOS.